# Remove woocommerce hidden products from wordpress default search result

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to remove woocommerce hidden products from default wordpress search result, hidden products are only hidden when doing a woocommerce search. Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the search loop and use the following codes below

```
$_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
$_product = $_pf->get_product($id); // assuming $id is available as the code is inside the loop
$_product->is_visible()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Woocommerce 3+ this changed from metadata to a taxonomy

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_query_fix' );
function search_query_fix( $query = false ) {
  if(!is_admin() && is_search()){
    $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'exclude-from-search',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        )
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code (several years later) and it works to solve the hidden products function BUT it does something very funky with my header and footer links (seems it shows all translated versions which are normally not visible). Any clue how this code can be tweaked to work with the current versions of woocommerce and wordpress?